# Device or resource busy while configuring gpio as a char device

Tags: c, embedded, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, gpio

I am trying to configure a GPIO pin as output but it is failing with the reason of device or resource busy. The pin is configured as output, open-drain and belongs to the group of `gpiochip24` at offset 3. On reading the information from line info IOCTL I can see that the flag is 3 (`OPEN_DRAIN`) and is assigned a consumer. But when I try to configure the pin as output with a default value using the `GPIO_GET_LINEHANDLE_IOCTL`, the IOCTL fails.

```c
    int gpioFd = open("/dev/gpiochip24", 0);
    if (gpioFd < 0) {
       printf("ERROR: GPIO chip fail\n");
       return -1;
    }

    struct gpiohandle_request req;
    req.flags |= GPIOHANDLE_REQUEST_OUTPUT;
    req.lineoffsets[0] = 3;    
    req.lines = 1;
    req.default_values[0] = 0;
    strcpy(req.consumer_label, "P_EN");
    int lhfd = ioctl(gpioFd, GPIO_GET_LINEHANDLE_IOCTL, &req);
    if(lhfd < 0)
    {
       int err = errno; 
       printf("Error No: %d\n", err); 
       printf("ERROR: Gpio Line handle\n");
       return -1;
    }
```

Output:

```
Error No: 16
ERROR: Gpio Line handle
```

I looked inside */sys/kernel/debug/gpio* to understand who is using the resource but I get the following response:

```
gpiochip24: GPIOs 99-106, parent: platform/139b0000.pinctrl, gpg2
```

How do I resolve this error of device busy?

Comment: Hint: use `perror` or at least `strerror` to get the error message. e.g. `perror("GPIO line handle");` -> output: `GPIO line handle: Device or resource busy`

Answer (score 2):

Because `req` is local, it has garbage when allocated, and it doesn't look like the code is initializing it properly, and - in particular - the `flags` value probably has junk in it.

```
req.flags |= GPIOHANDLE_REQUEST_OUTPUT;  // no
req.flags  = GPIOHANDLE_REQUEST_OUTPUT;  // yes
```

would work around this particular issue, but be sure all the other fields in this structure are not relying on junk.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the bug. I cleared the local variable req and assigned the flag directly rather than modifying its bit but the response is still the same i.e. device or resource is busy.

Comment: Hmm. What hardware / OS are you running this one?

Comment: It is an embedded android application on an exynos chip.

Comment: @Cherbo, update your Q with output of `gpioinfo gpiochip24`.

Comment: @0andriy The system does not have the library of libgpiod which supports the command gpioinfo. Is there another way where I can extract the information.

Comment: @Cherbo, it's an easiest one. Another I guess is to compile GPIO tools from kernel sources and run `lsgpio`.